# Render Process is Gone in Google Chrome While adding 100,000 rows to a DataTable

Tags: javascript, ajax, performance, google-chrome, datatables

Im loading 100,000 rows of data from my php BackEnd using Ajax as follow:

1. First an ajax call get the number of rows , pages "chunks" and the total of records to load from a click event (I already try with 10K rows to 50K rows and everything works ok).

```
 $('#btnObtenerData').on('click', (e) => {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'getData.php',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                data: {
                    "accion": "getConteo"
                }
            }).done((response) => {
                totalPaginas = response.totalPaginas,
                    totalFilas = response.totalFilas;
                console.log(totalPaginas, totalFilas);
                if (totalPaginas > 0) {
                    cargarPaginas(totalFilas, totalPaginas);
                }
            })
        });
```

2. Once the first call is done **cargarPaginas** is executed, this function contains the followed code.

```
     function cargarPaginas(totalFilas, totalPaginas) {
            //paginar(1,totalFilas,totalPaginas);
            let arr = [];
            let pages = totalPaginas;
            for (var i = 0; i < totalPaginas; i++) {
                console.log(totalPaginas);
                arr.push({
                    page: i + 1,
                    rows: totalFilas,
                    pages: pages
                });
            }
            var p = $.when();
            arr.forEach(function(item, key) {
                p = p.then(function() {
                    return paginar(item.page, item.rows, item.pages);
                });
            });
        }
```

And getPagina y paginar run the followed code as well

```
      function getPagina(numeroPagina) {
            let pagina = $("#paginacion").find('a.activa');
            $("#tbodyReporte").find("[data-pagina='" + numeroPagina + "']").css("display", "");
            $("#tbodyReporte").children("tr[data-pagina!='" + numeroPagina + "']").css("display", "none");
            $(pagina).trigger('click');
        }

        function paginar(paginaNumero = 1, totalFilas = 1000, totalPaginas = 0) {
            return $.ajax({
                url: 'getData.php',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                data: {
                    accion: "getData",
                    "numeroPagina": paginaNumero,
                    "numeroFilas": totalFilas
                }
            }).done((response) => {
                console.log(response);
                if (paginaNumero == 1) {
                    tabla = $('#gridReporte').DataTable({
                        data: response,
                        columns: [{
                                "data": "Factura"
                            },
                            {
                                "data": "Tipo de Servicio"
                            },
                            {
                                "data": "SERVICIO"
                            },
                            {
                                "data": "fecha de emision"
                            },
                            {
                                "data": "NContrato"
                            },
                            {
                                "data": "CLIENTE"
                            },
                            {
                                "data": "Tipo Pago"
                            },
                            {
                                "data": "CIUDAD"
                            },
                            {
                                "data": "COLONIA"
                            },
                            {
                                "data": "Oficial de Recuperacion"
                            },
                            {
                                "data": "MONEDA"
                            },
                            {
                                "data": "MORA"
                            },
                            {
                                "data": "Cargo por Servicio"
                            },
                            {
                                "data": "ISV"
                            },
                            {
                                "data": "Total Factura"
                            },
                            {
                                "data": "N Cliente"
                            },
                            {
                                "data": "Dia Mora"
                            },
                            {
                                "data": "NUMRECIBO"
                            },
                            {
                                "data": "Agente Mant Cartera"
                            },
                            {
                                "data": "Nombre Vendedor"
                            },
                            {
                                "data": "Clase Cliente"
                            },
                            {
                                "data": "Tipo Vendedor"
                            }
                        ],
                        dom: 'Bfrtip',
                        buttons: [
                            'excelHtml5'
                        ],
                        "language": idioma_spanol,
                        "pageLength": 500,
                        "columnDefs": [{
                            "targets": '_all',
                            "createdCell": function(td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
                                $(td).css('padding', '1px');
                                $(td).css('margin', '0px');
                            }
                        }]
                    });
                } else {
                    tabla.rows.add(response)
                        .draw();
                }
            })
        }
```

Like I said when a load of 50K records or less is made everything goes well

[image: successful load]

But when I try to load more than 90K records the Browser Tab crash like this:

[image]

I would like to understand why is this happening? and How to fix it.

Thanks in advice

Comment: Try to run the test without loading the dataTable. That might help you isolate the source of the problem.

Comment: "*I would like to understand why is this happening?*" it is because you never, ever will be able to load +100k records into the DOM. You must look at serverside processing instead.

Comment: @davidkonrad I realize that I can handle 50K records pretty good, But I will like to know if there is a way to dump those 100K records with php into a csv or excel file without killing the momory

Comment: @stanchacon You should prepare the dump files serverside (or build them dynamically serverside) that will only cause some delay for the user, not trouble the client / browser.

Comment: @davidkonrad I have tried to do this but the problem is that there are many users that can access this report and sometimes they filter to get 100 records other times around 100K or more